# Trouble Running C Code - "No such file or directory" Error

Tags: c, cs50

Question:

I'm currently working on the CS50 "hours" exercise and encountering an issue when trying to run my C code. While my code was working fine for previous exercises, I'm now getting a "No such file or directory" error when attempting to execute it using `./hours`. I'm unsure what's causing this problem. Could someone please help me troubleshoot and understand what might be going wrong?

Details:

Directory Structure: I've checked that my code file `hours.c` is in the same directory where I'm trying to execute it using `./hours`.

Compilation: I'm compiling my code using gcc with the command `gcc -o hours hours.c -lcs50`, as I'm using functions from the cs50 library.

Executable Name: After compilation, the executable is named `hours`. However, even when I try to run it with `./hours`, I'm encountering the "No such file or directory" error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then please [edit] your question to improve it, like showing the directory structure and the code itself (in the form of a [mre]).

Comment: Try ls -l hours to see the ownership and permissions are what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

hours.c is the c source file containing your code.
hours is the executable file.
First, make sure you're in the current directory as your hours.c file, do ls -l or ls-a.

You should see your files in current directory.
Next, you may need to give your executable permissions so type "sudo chmod 777 hours" or "sudo chmod 777 ./hours"

Lastly, run your program by typing ./hours
Make sure there are no spaces and type it as is.